# Не подключаются файлы

Tags: javascript, node.js

Только начал изучать node.js и столкнулся с проблемой: не отображаются стили. Сами стили подключены к html-документу, но при запуске сервера они не отображаются, также происходит и с другими файлами, которые подключаются к html-документу, например, javascript, но такого не происходит с картинками.

Вот просто пример:

**html-документ**

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> // Подключаю стили
</head>

<body>
    <h1>some text</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

css-файл

---

```css
h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

index.js

---

```js
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'), (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });

        res.end(data);
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server has been started on localhost:${PORT}...`)
});
```

И структура сайта

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перейдя на `localhost:3000` вижу обычный черный заголовок. Как можно решить эту проблему? Как вообще принято решать подобного рода проблемы?

### UPD

---

Я проверил sources в панели разработчика. Там есть css-файл, но его содержание эквивалентно html-документу. Теперь я вообще ничего не понимаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам так или иначе придётся делать маршрутизацию - самописную или через фреймфорки. Можете почитать например про "общепринятый" express и [его маршрутизацию](https://expressjs.com/ru/guide/routing.html). Без фреймфорка это скорее всего займёт слишком много времени и будет велосипед с багами и уязвимостями. И фреймворк довольно прост в понимании. Также можете в ютубе посмотреть обучения по ноде и экспресс, там это всё объясняется за час, на мой взгляд это лучше чем методом тыка тратить время.

Answer (score 2):

Каждое обращение к сайту вы отдаёте вашу html страничку. Вы неправильно поняли принцип работы http сервера.

Comment: Прошу, объясните.

Comment: http сервер запрашивает файл стилей также, как и вашу страницу, но вы всегда отдаёте страницу. Вы должны так же отдавать таким же образом и другие файлы.